# Pointers are being invalidated some how, which leads to an Access Violation

Tags: c++, pointers, native, access-violation, invalidation

Dev Environment is VS2010 and language is mixed C# (GUI) and C++ (Sim Engine), compiling for 32-bit Windows. The exceptions occur on every version of Windows we have tested with including 32-bit XP, 32-bit Vista, 32-bit 7, and 64-bit 7.

I am completely at a loss with this one. Because of the nature of the program (events-based simulation), the pointer is invalidated at some unknown point in time before we actually try to access it and get the AVE.

What I *do* know is that it is being invalidated in a very particular way, and I'm hoping someone out there might have an idea as to what could cause this. When the AVE happens, the pointer that it was trying to use has been changed to:

```
(original) - ((size * 2) - 1)
```

Where `original` is the original address pointed to by the pointer, and `size` is the size of the object being pointed to.

For example, one of the access violations occurred on a pointer that *should* have pointed to `0x58E0`, and the object had a size of `0x70`. Instead of pointing to `0x58E0`, it pointed to `0x5801` which is `0x58E0 - ((0x70 * 2) - 1)`. The same thing happens with another object of a different type and size, so it seems to be a very specific relationship.

Edit: In the above I am *not* talking about doing pointer arithmetic in the code, I am only showing the mathematical relationship between what the pointer *should* be and what it ends up as when we reference it and get the Access Violation Exception. Hope that clears things up.

Edit 2: I just realized that as far as I can remember, we have only seen this problem with objects that are members of a std vector. Is there something that we could have screwed up in our vector implementation that could have caused this behavior?

Comment: When doing pointer arithmetic, the unit is that of one object, not one byte. So multiplying by the size seems problematic; double-check that you understand pointer arithmetic. Perhaps you just mean `original - 1`.

Comment: @KerrekSB by the variable `original` he probably means the original address of the object interpreted as an integer

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough in the post. I'm not doing any pointer arithmetic in the code, the above was only to show the mathematical relationship between what the pointer _should_ be, and what it ends up being when we try to reference the (now) invalid pointer and get an Access Violation Exception.

Comment: Did you try a data breakpoint to be notified when pointer is modified ?

Comment: I tried, but since it is a mixed application VS will not let me create one. I'm currently trying to find a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the corruption suggests someone messed up using realloc.

Comment: I just did a "Find" in VS for "realloc" and it didn't find anything, so we're not calling it directly. In case it's of any significance, as far as I can think of, it seems like this problem has only been seen with objects that are members of vectors. Anything I could look for in our vector implementation that might be causing this kind of problem?

Comment: There you go. Vector calls realloc. Try storing pointers to objects in Vector instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I just realized that as far as I can remember, we have only seen this problem with objects that are members of a std vector. Is there something that we could have screwed up in our vector implementation that could have caused this behavior?

It's not a problem with the vector implementation, it's a problem with how you use it.

`vector` most certainly invalidates iterators and pointers to existing objects whenever it grows its capacity.  The peculiar mathematical relationship you're seeing is going to be related to the growth pattern of your particular implementation.

The solution is not to keep pointer to vector contents while the size of the vector is changing.  You could keep a pointer to the vector and an index, that would continue to be valid.

Comment: I should have been more specific: our vector only stores pointers to the objects. Does what you are talking about still apply in that case? Also, this has happened at least once with an object that was pointed to by a vector that only ever has 1 member during the entire duration of the scenario.

Comment: @gtftw: I don't see how that's "objects that are members of a `std::vector`".  If you have a pointer, and there's also a copy of that pointer in the vector, then the vector has nothing to do with it.  Or is the pointer stored in the vector being changed?